Forgot an account to get BitLocker key. Is there any way I can recover it?
My laptop recently experienced a failure and had to be taken in for maintenance. When I tried to start the laptop after the repair, it prompted me to enter a recovery key for BitLocker, the disk encryption software. Unfortunately, I do not recall setting up a BitLocker recovery key, nor do I have one saved elsewhere.
I have attempted to access my Microsoft and Gmail accounts, as well as the phone number associated with my Microsoft account, in the hopes of locating the BitLocker recovery key. However, I have been unable to find the key through these methods.
Is there a way for me to determine the exact email address or account that is registered with the BitLocker recovery ID displayed on my laptop? If I can identify the associated account, I may be able to access the recovery key from there. I do not have any physical copies of the recovery key, as I don't recall being prompted to save it manually.

A recovery key isn't necessarily associated with an account or backed up anywhere. // Check whether Secure Boot is enabled.

If you don't have the recovery key, and it was not saved to the Microsoft Account linked to the local account, then your only choice is to reinstall Windows.  This will over course overwrite the data on the HDD. In the future you should suspend BitLocker protection, before taking your device in for service, in order to avoid the situation you are in today.

@JoepvanSteen - What is the repair shop suppose to do? They performed actions, likely changing the configuration of the system in some way, and as a result the recovery is now required. Only the customer will have the recovery key. The customer, the author, does not have the recovery key.

Typically, the recovery key will be stored on the Microsoft account associated with the admin/primary logon ID on the computer in question. This assumes you logged into the computer with a Microsoft account and/or associated your logon with a Microsoft account in Windows.
The password should be the same as the one you login to Windows with, unless you set up Windows Hello or changed just your logon password at some point in the past.
It this Microsoft account does not work, you could try any other Microsoft accounts that were logged into the computer, but there is no way to tell which it would be.

Here's Microsoft's guide for Bitlocker Recovery for personal devices.
Here's Microsoft's actual Bitlocker recovery page, the one you'll need to login to with the Microsoft account associated with your computer.

